# Inbox messages are gone from Outlook Express 6 - Inbox.dbx too big

Tags: outlook-express

My Father uses Outlook Express 6 and had thousands of messages in his inbox. Suddenly Outlook Express says the inbox is empty. I think it kind of overflowed. The inbox points to a .dbx file with a size of 1,99 GB. Is there a way to restore those messages?

Comment: Indeed, I just learned the maximum capacity of Inbox.dbx is 2GB but I couldn't find any satisfactory solution yet.

Comment: Te maximum file size of any single file is 2.00 GB. This is a limitation of FAT32. See my answer for a free built in fix that addresses this

Comment: Nope. The max filesize in FAT32 is 4G minus 1 byte. The 2G is a limitation of OE ≤6.

Comment: @kinokijuf You're right, appologies to the OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checkout UnDBX - it's free. You should probably use it in recovery mode.

http://code.google.com/p/undbx

Answer (score 0):

First thing, make a copy of all the dbx files to another folder, then use this software to try and recover messages.

http://www.oemailrecovery.com/outlook-express-recovery.html

But its not free, just the best
http://www.oemailrecovery.com/buy.html

.